# Is it possible to use column names with spaces using prefix i for data.table join?

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to provide column name with space with the prefix i in data.table. Below is a simple example

```
X <- data.table(`First Column` = c(1,2,3), `Second Column` = c(4,5,6))
Y <- data.table(`First Column` = c(1,2,3), `Second Column` = c(7,8,9))
```

I want to perform something like this:

```
X[Y, on = "First Column", `Second Column` := i.`Second Column`]
```

Below is the expected output:

[image: output should be something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is `get` on the string `"i.Second Column"`

```
X[Y, `Second Column` := get("i.Second Column"), on = .(`First Column`)]

X
#   First Column Second Column
#1:            1             7
#2:            2             8
#3:            3             9
```

---

Or wrap the whole within backquotes

```
X[Y, on = .(`First Column`), `Second Column` := `i.Second Column`][]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
library(data.table)
X[Y, on = "First Column", `Second Column` := `i.Second Column`][]

#   First Column Second Column
#1:            1             7
#2:            2             8
#3:            3             9
```